# Silverlight app closing one window closes the parent window also

Tags: windows, silverlight

in our Silverlight app we open up a new Silverlight control hosted in a new HTML page and things work great as long as the user does not hit the browser close button before the secondary page loads. Then both browser windows disappear with no warning. I tried writing Javascript to handle the onbeforeunload but even this was not called. The idea was to warn the user that this action could be bad. So I then write a real simple sample app to repro the issue and here are the ni-lites:

add a button to the parent page:

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("TestControlTestPage.aspx"),
                UriKind.Relative), "searchresults", 
                "directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=yes,toolbar=no,resizable=yes");
```

This opens a new HTML Page hosting a new Silverlight control , newControl and in here I simulate the situation in our app where we must load some stuff from the server as follows:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

So there is delay before the loaded method is called, and if I press the X (Close) before the page loaded is called then both windows disappear.

as mentioned above I also have a tried adding javascript for the onbeforeunload but this was not called. Pretty ugly any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I am also having this issue, has anyone come up with a possible cause or solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution for [Stopping a user from leaving a Silverlight page](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=480)

I am not sure why your previous use of *onbeforeunload* failed, as it works really well, but perhaps you post that javascript code and we can work out that issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("askconfirm function set");  //make sure it is loaded
adjustSilverlightHeight();
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        alert("askconfirm");   //confirm it is called
        var control = document.getElementById("SilverlightControl");

        if (control.Content.Page) {
            var IsLoading = control.Content.Page.IsLoading();

            if (!IsLoading) {
                return;
            }

            return 'Closing this window before it loads can cause application instability , Please click  Stay on Page option';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When trying your Javascript I get a JS error: "Content.Page is null or not an object". When I added a test Content.Page is indeed null so it is a run-time error stopping your code working. Try the exact example from my blog link. Cheers

Comment: The issue is that if you are loading the silverlight control via javascript, the page might not be completely loaded yet. Using your example, you call a silverlight method from the JS, yet if it isnt loaded, how is this useful? Either way the onbeforeunloaded doesnt help in this context, even through pure JS because the timing makes it unreliable.